# add to cart button not working in mozila firefox

Tags: virtuemart

add to cart not working in mozila firefox but it is working in internet exploral,Netscape,crome...how can i solve this problem.
site url is::

http://www.botguruz.com/buy-a-bot.html?page=shop.browse&category_id=1&vmcchk=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [answered this question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914619/mozilla-firefox-doesnt-work-with-my-websites-add-to-cart-feature/1914644#1914644):

Get rid of the `return false;` in the `<form>`'s `onsubmit` attribute. If you just delete that in Firebug, you'll see the button works.

Your `handleAddToCart( this.id )` function should return a boolean - `false` if you don't want the submit button to work, `true` otherwise. Hardwiring in a `return false` to the `onsubmit` event means that whatever happens in the `handleAddToCart()` function, the form won't submit.

I don't know why it would work in other browsers.

It's this bit:

```
<form onsubmit="handleAddToCart( this.id );return false;"
      class="addtocart_form" id="addtocart50_1" name="addtocart"
      method="post" action="http://botguruz.com/index.php">
```

You need to delete the `return false;`